# How to create a Swift function (or class) and pass some variables

Tags: swift, class, variables, swift5

In PHP, I'm used to create a function like this

```
function fun ($one,$two) { return $two; }
```

later I can in PHP just do

```
$variable1 = "something";
$variable2 = "something2";
echo fun($variable1,$variable2);
```

but I'm new to Xcode / Swift 5

I created a class

```
class APIX {
    
    var urlxtra: String
    var deviceToken: String
       
    init(urlxtra: String, deviceToken: String) {
        
        self.urlxtra = urlxtra
        self.deviceToken = deviceToken
        
        let url = "https://www.api__url___.com/v1/"+deviceToken+"/"+urlxtra+"/"
        
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlObj!)
        
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        urlRequest.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!)
        
        task.resume()
        
    }
}
```

and call it like this it works

```
let apicall = APIX(urlxtra: "somthing1", deviceToken: "something2")
```

but when I do this

```
let stubToken = "somthing3";
let apicall = APIX(urlxtra: "somthing1", deviceToken: stubToken)
```

Xcode says :

```
Cannot use instance member 'stubToken' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between functions and classes -- they're very different things in both Swift and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you did something like this:

```
class Something {

    let stubToken = "somthing3";
    let apicall = APIX(urlxtra: "somthing1", deviceToken: stubToken)
}
```

Both are instance properties, initialized at the same time (their initialization order is not guaranteed) and hence one cannot depend on the other. You need to establish a dependency, so that `stubToken` is initialized before the `apicall`.

If `stubToken` is really a constant, make it static:

```
class Something {

    static let stubToken = "somthing3";
    let apicall = APIX(urlxtra: "somthing1", deviceToken: Something.stubToken)
}
```

If it's a variable, you can initialize `apicall` it in the `init`, or make the second variable `lazy` as the other answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

Several possible solutions

declare it as `lazy`

```
let stubToken = "somthing3";
lazy var apicall = APIX(urlxtra: "somthing1", deviceToken: stubToken)
```

or initialise it in an `init` method

```
let stubToken = "somthing3";
let apicall: APIX

init() {
    apicall = APIX(urlxtra: "somthing1", deviceToken: stubToken)
}
```

or if the variables can change then pass them to an init method

```
let apicall: APIX

init(urlxtra: String, stubToken: String) {
    apicall = APIX(urlxtra: urlxtra, deviceToken: stubToken)
}
```